# How to enable yaml files in Azure web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a static website using an Azure web app but I'm getting a 404 when trying to serve up `/swagger.yaml`

Do I need to enable yaml files in the configuration settings somewhere?  It seems to serve the html files fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable YAML files in Azure Web App, you could create `web.config` file to your webroot (`D:\home\site\wwwroot`) if not exists, and then add the following to it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".yaml" mimeType="text/x-yaml" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```